# How can I only create a file without opening it

Tags: c++

I've been trying to create a file without using system commands. This code I wrote has multiple problems, If i create fptr in the start and check it for NULLity then the double free or corruption occurs, otherwise this way it gives memory dump. Even through previous method I wasnt closing file more than once but I think there's something very simple hiding between the lines I cant see.

```
int main()
{
    char* filename;
    char x;
    cout << "enter filename.**: ";
    cin >> filename;
    struct stat buffer;
    if (! stat (filename, &buffer))
    {
         cout << ("It exists\n");
    }
    else
    {  
         FILE* fptr;    
         fptr = fopen (filename,"w");;
         fclose (fptr);
    }
}
```

Really Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: You forgot to allocate space for `filename`. (And since this is C++, use `std::string`.)

Comment: If you have a newer compiler you can use the [filesystem TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) that is part of what will be the C++17 standard.

Comment: how should i allocate space for filename?

Comment: @cmaster: There's no such function in the "standard C library".

Comment: @malloc _"how should i allocate space for filename?"_ Just use `std::string` rather.

Comment: i cant get it through. could you show me that^ in code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ please say you at least chuckled over the username of the person asking that question.

Comment: @malloc _"i cant get it through. could you show me that^ in code"_ I'm pretty sure you're smart enough to figure that our yourself. There are many examples you can find (including the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open)). Asking for _"gimme teh codez plz"_ is generally frowned upon here.

Comment: @user4581301 No, I'm a serious person. No chuckles, never.

Comment: well my point was that i couldnt find an example on allocating space to a file. also you sound like dany. anyways thanks for the link

Comment: Regarding "allocating space to a file." You don't. The file system does. You write to a file and the file system makes sure you have space. You don't write to the file, you have an empty file. There may be OS-specific commands to presize a file, but I know of none in the standard library or in the forthcoming filesystem library.

Comment: @cmaster `creat` is a POSIX function, not a C or C++ standard function. Different library standard. Ditto `open`.

Comment: @cmaster: `man` is not a C standard library reference. It's a Unix help system.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, I see my error. Thanks. It just seemed so crazy that the C standard, being pretty much the lowest-level common basis available everywhere, would just define the high-level `fopen()` which requires the much more fundamental `open()` to even be implementable, and omit that low level prerequisite. Oh, well, standards *are* crazy sometimes...

Comment: @cmaster Not so crazy. A lot of really good ideas don't make it into the standard because they are impossible* to implement on some platforms that C++ supports. *where impossible merely means we don't have a good way to do it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mknod()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html) on some systems (such as Linux; note this is not portable to all operating systems).

```
if (mknod(filename, S_IFREG|0666, 0) != 0) {
    throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category());
}
```

In portable code you will have to open a file in order to create it.

Comment: What notable platform does not allow creating a file without opening it? Windows has CreateFileA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea

Comment: @matvore: I did not say there is a platform where it's impossible to create a file without opening it.  I said "In portable code."  `CreateFileA()` is not portable (and neither is `mknod()`).  So yes, most systems have a way to do it, but not a single uniform way across all systems (by contrast to opening a file to create it, which can be done portably).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I genuinely wondered if there was a platform that didn't allow it.

My idea of portable code is to write against each API you need to support and select the right code during build and compile. But I admit this definition may be off.